Issue Binding Selenium WebDriver to Existing Chrome Instance with Remote Debugging Port
I’m trying to open a Selenium browser with a specific Chrome profile.
The issue arises when I already have a Chrome instance running. If I run my code while Chrome is open, it only launches a new browser (using Popen), but it doesn’t bind to Selenium WebDriver or navigate to the URL. However, when I kill all Chrome instances and rerun the code, Popenopens the browser with the specified debugging port, successfully binds to Selenium WebDriver, and navigates to the link.
I’m not sure if I’m misunderstanding how Selenium works with remote debugging or if there’s something wrong in my code. Any insights would be appreciated!
This is the code :
import subprocess
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import socket
import time

def find_free_port():
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.bind(('', 0))
        return s.getsockname()[1]

def openBrowser():
    # ChromeDriver path
    driver_path = "DrivrePath"
    
    # Find a free port for remote debugging
    RDP = find_free_port()
    
    # Start a new Chrome instance with remote debugging
    proc = subprocess.Popen(
        ["C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe", 
         f"--remote-debugging-port={RDP}", 
         "--user-data-dir=./chrome_profile_new"],
        shell=False
    )
    # Wait for Chrome to start
    time.sleep(2)

    # Set up Chrome options
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", f"localhost:{RDP}")
    
    # Set up the ChromeDriver service
    service = Service(executable_path=driver_path)
    
    # Create a new Chrome driver instance
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
    
    # Navigate to the desired URL
    driver.get("https://www.google.com")
    
    return driver, proc

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from multiprocessing import Process
    
    p = Process(target=openBrowser)
    p.start()
    p.join()


I’ve attempted to specify the user-data-dir for my profile, but it doesn’t seem to work. Now, I’m trying to use Chrome with a remote debugging port.
Also I thought that making the code in a separate process would work, but still it doesn't
